# How should I deal with Nan values if they occupy a great portion of the data set?

Tags: classification, missing-data

I am trying to make a classifier that predicts whether a patient is diabetic or not. I am working on this [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/iammustafatz/diabetes-prediction-dataset). While doing EDA, I found that in the column of `smoking_history`, 32887 rows out of 100000 rows have the value `no_info` (the distribution is shown below). How should I deal with this category in order not to degrade the model's performance?
[image: dist]

Comment: Look up missing-value imputation.

Comment: @DoctorMilt I know about imputation. But as you can see the missing values occupy 34% of the data. I don't think i can just impute the missing values

Comment: What you can do depends on *why* these values are missing.  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: @whuber i actually don't know why they are missing. I am just using the data set as it is.

Comment: What keeps you from just treating this as another category and letting the classifier figure out whether this potentially has predictive value?

Comment: @StephanKolassa this will not affect the model's performance?

Comment: The key question is: compared to *what*? Of course, having the actual values will likely be better. (Likely, not, guaranteedly.) But you don't have the actual values, and imputing is problematic, especially for such a large fraction of your dataset. Yes, using this as another category might yield worse performance than dropping the feature altogether. Just as for any other feature. So this is not specific to having NAs.

Comment: Naturally, the less data you have to impute the better for statistical estimation. However, I am not aware of any special threshold that says that 34% missing data is too much in order to compute some form of imputation. Bayesian imputation can handle relatively small samples of non-missing data if the prior is well-justified.